# Number average for nobody

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, printing

I cant execute the break when i put in 999 it just keeps asking for more scores somone help

```
score = 0
```

total_score = 0

```
while True:
    scores = float(input("Enter test score: ")
    if score in range (0,100):
        total_score = score + total_score
        score = score + 1
     
    elif score = 999:
         break
    else:
        print("Test score must be from 0 through 100")

average_score = total_score / score
print("Total score", total_score )
print("Average Score", average_score)
```

Comment: Is that Python? You should tag your question with the language. I don't know much about Python, but does it actually allow unbalanced parens like that? I.e. `float(input("Enter test score: ")`. More to the point though, you are storing the user input in `scores`, but then using a completely different variable named `score` for the comparison against `999`. It's not surprising to me that that might not work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peter mentioned, using `score` and `scores` is confusing. It is better to use a variable like `cnt` to keep score count. Note that `range(0,100)` only goes to 99. Use `range(0,101)` to include 100. You also have some syntax errors causing issues.

Try this code:

```
total_score = 0  # sum of scores
cnt = 0   # score count

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter test score (0-100): "))
    if score in range (0,101):  # 0-100
        total_score += score
        cnt += 1 
     
    elif score == 999:
         break
    else:
        print("Test score must be from 0 through 100")

average_score = total_score / cnt
print("Score count", cnt )
print("Total score", total_score )
print("Average Score", average_score)
```

Output

```
Enter test score (0-100): 20
Enter test score (0-100): 30
Enter test score (0-100): 40
Enter test score (0-100): 50
Enter test score (0-100): 60
Enter test score (0-100): 999
Score count 5
Total score 200
Average Score 40.0
```